# Spring Boot tutorial, error by running simple application

Tags: spring-boot, groovy

According to this tutorial https://www.tutorialspoint.com/spring_boot/spring_boot_quick_start.htm I am trying to execute a simple Groovy file as following:

```
@Controller
class Example {
   @RequestMapping("/")
   @ResponseBody
   public String hello() {
      "Hello Spring Boot"
   }
}
```

but I see the following error:

```
startup failed:
General error during conversion: org.eclipse.aether.resolution.DependencyResolutionException: Failed to collect dependencies at org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter:jar:2.3.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT

org.springframework.boot.cli.compiler.grape.DependencyResolutionFailedException: org.eclipse.aether.resolution.DependencyResolutionException: Failed to collect dependencies at org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter:jar:2.3.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT
        at org.springframework.boot.cli.compiler.grape.AetherGrapeEngine.resolve(AetherGrapeEngine.java:298)
        at org.springframework.boot.cli.compiler.grape.AetherGrapeEngine.grab(AetherGrapeEngine.java:116)
        at groovy.grape.Grape.grab(Grape.java:166)
        at groovy.grape.GrabAnnotationTransformation.visit(GrabAnnotationTransformation.java:376)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.transform.ASTTransformationVisitor$3.call(ASTTransformationVisitor.java:319)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.control.CompilationUnit.applyToSourceUnits(CompilationUnit.java:954)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.control.CompilationUnit.doPhaseOperation(CompilationUnit.java:636)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.control.CompilationUnit.processPhaseOperations(CompilationUnit.java:612)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.control.CompilationUnit.compile(CompilationUnit.java:589)
        at org.springframework.boot.cli.compiler.GroovyCompiler.compile(GroovyCompiler.java:197)
        at org.springframework.boot.cli.command.run.SpringApplicationRunner.compile(SpringApplicationRunner.java:125)
        at org.springframework.boot.cli.command.run.SpringApplicationRunner.compileAndRun(SpringApplicationRunner.java:97)
        at org.springframework.boot.cli.command.run.RunCommand$RunOptionHandler.run(RunCommand.java:111)
        at org.springframework.boot.cli.command.options.OptionHandler.run(OptionHandler.java:85)
        at org.springframework.boot.cli.command.OptionParsingCommand.run(OptionParsingCommand.java:54)
        at org.springframework.boot.cli.command.CommandRunner.run(CommandRunner.java:219)
        at org.springframework.boot.cli.command.CommandRunner.runAndHandleErrors(CommandRunner.java:171)
        at org.springframework.boot.cli.SpringCli.main(SpringCli.java:64)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at org.springframework.boot.loader.MainMethodRunner.run(MainMethodRunner.java:48)
        at org.springframework.boot.loader.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:87)
        at org.springframework.boot.loader.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:51)
        at org.springframework.boot.loader.JarLauncher.main(JarLauncher.java:52)
Caused by: org.eclipse.aether.resolution.DependencyResolutionException: Failed to collect dependencies at org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter:jar:2.3.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT
        at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultRepositorySystem.resolveDependencies(DefaultRepositorySystem.java:351)
        at org.springframework.boot.cli.compiler.grape.AetherGrapeEngine.resolve(AetherGrapeEngine.java:293)
        ... 25 more
Caused by: org.eclipse.aether.collection.DependencyCollectionException: Failed to collect dependencies at org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter:jar:2.3.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT
        at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultDependencyCollector.collectDependencies(DefaultDependencyCollector.java:293)
        at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultRepositorySystem.resolveDependencies(DefaultRepositorySystem.java:307)
        ... 26 more
Caused by: org.eclipse.aether.resolution.ArtifactDescriptorException: Failed to read artifact descriptor for org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter:jar:2.3.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT
        at org.apache.maven.repository.internal.DefaultArtifactDescriptorReader.loadPom(DefaultArtifactDescriptorReader.java:276)
        at org.apache.maven.repository.internal.DefaultArtifactDescriptorReader.readArtifactDescriptor(DefaultArtifactDescriptorReader.java:192)
        at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultDependencyCollector.resolveCachedArtifactDescriptor(DefaultDependencyCollector.java:539)
        at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultDependencyCollector.getArtifactDescriptorResult(DefaultDependencyCollector.java:522)
        at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultDependencyCollector.processDependency(DefaultDependencyCollector.java:411)
        at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultDependencyCollector.processDependency(DefaultDependencyCollector.java:365)
        at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultDependencyCollector.process(DefaultDependencyCollector.java:353)
        at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultDependencyCollector.collectDependencies(DefaultDependencyCollector.java:256)
        ... 27 more
Caused by: org.eclipse.aether.resolution.ArtifactResolutionException: Could not transfer artifact org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter:pom:2.3.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT from/to spring-snapshot (https://repo.spring.io/snapshot): proxy.host
        at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultArtifactResolver.resolve(DefaultArtifactResolver.java:422)
        at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultArtifactResolver.resolveArtifacts(DefaultArtifactResolver.java:224)
        at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultArtifactResolver.resolveArtifact(DefaultArtifactResolver.java:201)
        at org.apache.maven.repository.internal.DefaultArtifactDescriptorReader.loadPom(DefaultArtifactDescriptorReader.java:261)
        ... 34 more
Caused by: org.eclipse.aether.transfer.ArtifactTransferException: Could not transfer artifact org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter:pom:2.3.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT from/to spring-snapshot (https://repo.spring.io/snapshot): proxy.host
        at org.eclipse.aether.connector.basic.ArtifactTransportListener.transferFailed(ArtifactTransportListener.java:52)
        at org.eclipse.aether.connector.basic.BasicRepositoryConnector$TaskRunner.run(BasicRepositoryConnector.java:365)
        at org.eclipse.aether.util.concurrency.RunnableErrorForwarder$1.run(RunnableErrorForwarder.java:75)
        at org.eclipse.aether.connector.basic.BasicRepositoryConnector$DirectExecutor.execute(BasicRepositoryConnector.java:583)
        at org.eclipse.aether.connector.basic.BasicRepositoryConnector.get(BasicRepositoryConnector.java:259)
        at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultArtifactResolver.performDownloads(DefaultArtifactResolver.java:498)
        at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultArtifactResolver.resolve(DefaultArtifactResolver.java:399)
        ... 37 more
Caused by: java.net.UnknownHostException: proxy.host
        at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName0(InetAddress.java:1281)
        at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName(InetAddress.java:1193)
        at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName(InetAddress.java:1127)
        at org.apache.http.impl.conn.SystemDefaultDnsResolver.resolve(SystemDefaultDnsResolver.java:45)
        at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultClientConnectionOperator.resolveHostname(DefaultClientConnectionOperator.java:263)
        at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultClientConnectionOperator.openConnection(DefaultClientConnectionOperator.java:162)
        at org.apache.http.impl.conn.ManagedClientConnectionImpl.open(ManagedClientConnectionImpl.java:326)
        at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.tryConnect(DefaultRequestDirector.java:605)
        at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.execute(DefaultRequestDirector.java:440)
        at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.doExecute(AbstractHttpClient.java:835)
        at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:72)
        at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:56)
        at org.apache.http.impl.client.DecompressingHttpClient.execute(DecompressingHttpClient.java:164)
        at org.eclipse.aether.transport.http.HttpTransporter.execute(HttpTransporter.java:296)
        at org.eclipse.aether.transport.http.HttpTransporter.implGet(HttpTransporter.java:252)
        at org.eclipse.aether.spi.connector.transport.AbstractTransporter.get(AbstractTransporter.java:67)
        at org.eclipse.aether.connector.basic.BasicRepositoryConnector$GetTaskRunner.runTask(BasicRepositoryConnector.java:453)
        at org.eclipse.aether.connector.basic.BasicRepositoryConnector$TaskRunner.run(BasicRepositoryConnector.java:360)
        ... 42 more

1 error
```

I already searched by Google and I found this old discussion, but it doesn't help me.

Answer (score 2):

It seems that there is something wrong with your proxy configuration and java is not able to download the dependencies. It can't resolve the `proxy.host` variable.

You must have set a proxy configuration to your java instance. Try to resolve this configuration problem and it should work.

If you are working with Spring Build Snapshots remember to configure the snapshots repository. For more info see https://www.baeldung.com/spring-maven-repository.

Comment: Thank you very much for your reply but your link doesn't help me. Can you please explain me a little bit more? I don't understand what I have exactly to do.

Comment: It's hard to tell you where you configured the proxy.host which your application is using. How do you start your application?